# Abort a QCloseEvent

Tags: qt5, qevent

In my application, I am handling a QCloseEvent (when the close button X was pressed):

```
void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent* event)
{
    if ( !isAbortedFilestoSave() ) {
      this->close();
    }
    // else abort
}
```

The if clause is triggereed when no abort was pressed. I would like to implement an else clause where a QCloseEvent is aborted? How?

Comment: Check http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcloseevent.html about ignoring an event and maybe see the example there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the `ignore()` on the event to "abort it" - to let Qt know you don't want the widget to actually close.

> The isAccepted() function returns true if the event's receiver has agreed to close the widget; call accept() to agree to close the widget and call ignore() if the receiver of this event does not want the widget to be closed.

Also, no need to call `close()` yourself - the "X" button does that already, that's why you receive a close event!

So your code should be:

```
void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent* event)
{
    // accept close event if are not aborted
    event->setAccepted(!isAbortedFilestoSave());
}
```